# How to convert directory SASS/SCSS to CSS via command line?

Tags: sass

I tried:

```
sass-convert --from scss --to css --recursive app/assets/stylesheets temp
```

But this only converts css to SASS, and I want the other way around.

Then I looked at the sass command, but it doesn't look like I can pass it a directory.

Comment: Yes, but I could not find a way to convert an entire directory with one sass command. The sass command only seems to do one file at a time, am I wrong? I know the sass --watch command will watch a directory for changes, but I need a single command line entry that will process a directory when I need to. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course. It seems that you can watch a directory, but I can't get it to work where it just converts a directory with one command (not watch for changes). Can you show me an example of a single command line string that can convert a directory?

Comment: Pretty easy: `sass --update www/_src/sass:www/css/` . Reference: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html

Comment: @Hawk, the directory thing only works (at least for me on osx) if I have previously compiled the individual files. Sass seems to rely on .sass-cache or .map to know what and where to name files.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

To do a one-time Sass compile instead of a `watch`, you can do this from the command line:

```
sass --update scss:css
```

To have Sass import one file (usually a partial, with a `_` starting the filename), you can do this inside a Sass file:

```
@import "_base.scss";
```

This way, Sass knows *where* you want the include to occur.

By default, Sass can't import an entire directory. The [Sass Globbing gem](https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-globbing), however, can.  You can install it from the command line:

```
gem install sass-globbing
```

And then watch with it:

```
sass -r sass-globbing --watch sass_dir:css_dir
```

Note that globbing will import files alphabetically, so be sure your CSS will cascade appropriately if this occurs.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. FWIW, my CSS file output was in the same order as the input. The files were not rearranged alphabetically.

Answer (score 20):

Use the `sass` command followed by the `input file name and path`, a colon (`:`) and the desired `output file name and path`. If the output file does not already exist Sass will generate it. For example,

```
sass sass/main.scss:css/main.css
```

However, this is a one-off command that would require being run every time you want to generate a new CSS file. A simpler and handier method is to use Sass's built-in `--watch` flag. This watches for changes to your Sass file and automatically runs the compile command each time you save changes.

```
sass --watch sass/main.scss:css/main.css
```

If you have multiple Sass files within a directory you can watch for changes to any file within that directory:

```
sass --watch sass:css
```

Sass also has four CSS output styles available: `nested`, `expanded`, `compact` and `compressed`. These can be used thus:

```
sass --watch sass:css --style compressed
```

Refer to [the Sass documentation](http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html) for more.

Answer (score 12):

to that, simply go your project directory and do this :

```
sass --update sass-dir:assets/css
```

with **sass-dir** the directory containing your actual sass files and **assets/css** the desired output directory.

Hope this could help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`compass`](http://compass-style.org/) to convert Sass files into CSS.

To initialize the `config.rb`, try:

```
compass init --syntax=sass --css-dir=css --javascripts-dir=js
```

Once you've the configuration file, try:

```
compass compile
```

or by specifying the file explicitly: `compass compile sass/foo.scss`.

---

To install it, try:

```
sudo gem update
sudo gem install sass compass
```

Comment: The OP is not asking about Compass, this is not a tool request question (hint: the question would be closed it it were).

Comment: @cimmanon This answer answers the title question (how to convert sass to css via cmd) and that was the main reason I've found this question and in my case `compass` did the job as `sass` didn't work for me, therefore I think awareness of alternatives can be useful for further readers.

Comment: Unless your project requires Compass, there is no reason why Sass would not work.

Comment: Yes, it required Compass, as the site was based on [Zen](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen) theme so it had a lot of missing imports/references.

Answer (score 1):

https://sass-lang.com/guide

[image]

you can use

```
sass --watch [input folder path]:[output folder path]
```

i tried running it in a new terminal and after that sass watches the folder and compiles upon any changes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

`sass --watch file.sass:file.css`

or

`sass --watch folderSass:foldercss`

if you want to create css.main you can use this code

`sass --watch sass:css --style compressed`