# compling mutiple sass files into multiple css in gruntfile.js not working

Tags: sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-sass

I have my folder structure as below

-*project_folder*

- sass

  - vendors
  - modules
  - partials

    - sass1.scss
    - sass2.scss
- css
- index.html

I want to compile sass files without compass, using grunt to each seperate css files, (sass1.css , sass2.css)

I tried with the code

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({

// SASS config
sass: {
    dist: {
     options: {
       style: 'nested',
       sourcemap: 'none',
       cache: false
     },
         files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'sass',
            src: ['*.scss'],
            dest: 'css/'
        }]
     }
    }
  });
```

But this isn't generating the css files. Please provide your solution.

Comment: can you confirm source file path ? is it scss/partials/*.scss or sass/partials/*.scss

Comment: Yes, Source file path is sass/partials/*.scss , as i have mentioned the above folder structure.

Comment: I also tried with 
      `sass: {
       dist: {
         options: {
           style: 'nested',
           sourcemap: 'none',
           cache: false
         },
         /*files: {
           'css/*.css': [
             'sass/partials/*.scss'
           ]
         }*/
         files: {
           'css/*.css' : 'sass/partials/*.scss'
         }
       }
     }`
But it isn't working.

Comment: My issue is the same as in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611885/compile-multiple-sass-files-in-multiple-directories-into-multiple-css-files-in

and using grunt sass