# Can anyone tell me how to compile sass into css automatically?

Tags: css, sass

I had to rewrite this every time I want to see a live preview.

```
sass stylesheet.scss stylesheet.css
```

Comment: Explain your question in more detail kindly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert directory SASS/SCSS to CSS via command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439914/how-to-convert-directory-sass-scss-to-css-via-command-line)

Comment: You can use a software.
I use Koala App to do this for me. He runs automatically and watches for the file changing.
Is tricky to config, but will help you a lot.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I use `sass --watch stylesheet.scss:stylesheet.css`. When saving your `.scss` file, it'll automatically update the `.css` file.

You might also consider `sass --watch stylesheet.scss:stylesheet.css --style expanded --sourcemap=none` to keep the `.css` file readable.

I'd recommend the [Sass Workflow class on Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/sass-workflow/?start=0).

Comment: Thank you. that's very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Try out Grunt or Gulp with Sass: A great tutorial: https://www.taniarascia.com/getting-started-with-grunt-and-sass/

Answer (score 1):

You need something to compile it automatically. As an example, there are solutions that use node.js to automatically compile for you on your computer. One tool is Foundation for Websites by Zurb.

You can install the application which will automatically compile sass for you.

For more information, check out: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

`sass --watch file.sass:file.css`

or

`sass --watch foldersass:foldercss`

Answer (score -2):

Sass can be compiled automatically using below command:

```
sass --watch SASS_SOURCE_PATH:CSS_BUILD_PATH --style=expanded --no-source-map
```

Where:

- `SASS_SOURCE_PATH`: Path of sass file
- `CSS_BUILD_PATH`: Path of build CSS file. Where do you want to save CSS file
- `--no-source-map`: will not output a map file, which is not readable.
- `--style=expanded`: will expand CSS to human readable.

Comment: This is the same answer than the one already existing. Please don't answer questions if there is nothing more to say