# How to change this SASS code into a plain CSS code?

Tags: css, sass

This is the SASS code I want to change into a plain CSS

```
@media (min-width: $md) {
 nav ul {
   justify-content: flex-end;
 }
```

I've been using a compiler in vscode and only this code cant compile into a plain CSS

Comment: Maybe doublicate to [SO - `How to convert directory SASS/SCSS to CSS via command line?`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19439914/10655742)

Comment: Do you want to do it with CLI (terminal), or with nodejs / ruby?

Comment: No mate, just change this SASS code into a plain CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for nodejs and npm and that package [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass)

```sh
npm install -g sass
sass <input.scss> [output.css]
```

The `$md` variable needs to be defined as well.

Comment: On ubuntu you can add also the packege `sass` via `apt install sass`